# Error when including 2 deps that both have stellar-base as a subdependency

Tags: javascript-sdk, xdr

When I include both `stellar-hd-wallet` and `stellar-sdk` in my project I get errors when requiring them both as stellar-base is included twice which also imports the generated XDR types twice causing the below error.

Any suggestions?

```
Error: XDR Error:Value is already defined
    at TypeBuilder.define (/code/blockchain-client/node_modules/js-xdr/lib/config.js:341:17)
    at TypeBuilder.typedef (/code/blockchain-client/node_modules/js-xdr/lib/config.js:247:14)
    at /code/blockchain-client/node_modules/stellar-hd-wallet/node_modules/stellar-base/lib/generated/stellar-xdr_generated.js:1:259
    at Object.config (/code/blockchain-client/node_modules/js-xdr/lib/config.js:38:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (//code/blockchain-client/node_modules/stellar-hd-wallet/node_modules/stellar-base/lib/generated/stellar-xdr_generated.js:1:234)
```

These are the related deps in my package.json:

```
"stellar-hd-wallet": "0.0.6",
"stellar-sdk": "^0.9.2"
```

Comment: What version of NPM or Yarn are you using? Both packages specify the same version of stellar-base so your package manager should be able to dedupe it for you.

Comment: I'm using npm version 6.1.0

Comment: Is there anything else that installs stellar-base besides stellar-hd-wallet or stellar-sdk?

It looks like stellar-base is not getting deduped by npm since I see that it's under /node_modules/stellar-hd-wallet/node_modules/stellar-base and it should just be under /node_modules/stellar-base if there's no package conflicts.

Can you try running `npm ls` to see if stellar-base is included by something else?

Comment: No, just those 2
├─┬ stellar-hd-wallet@0.0.6
│ └── stellar-base@0.7.8
└─┬ stellar-sdk@0.9.2
  └── stellar-base@0.7.8

Comment: This should happen automatically, but can you run npm dedupe to see if that helps. Or delete node_modules folder and npm install again.

Comment: That was after deleting node_modules and reinstalling. Dedupe fixes it but I really shouldn't have to do that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that you got the answer on github, but for anyone else looking I'll link it here:
https://github.com/stellar/js-stellar-sdk/issues/191

```
This is fixed in:

js-xdr@1.0.4
stellar-base@0.8.2
stellar-sdk@0.10.2
```